# Making ag-Grid grouping in Angular2 faster

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

[image]I am considering to use ag-Grid for our purposes. We need to load huge amount of rows (~50,000) to the ag-Grid. 
In addition, we have to show the rows with **grouping** (see the attached screenshot).
However, after adding 'ag-Grid' with grouping properties, the grid loaded **very very slow and sometimes even stacked**. Also the expand/collapse options are very slow.

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
  rowData:this.rowData,
  columnDefs:this.columnDefs,
  enableFilter: true,
  maxBlockInCache: 100,
  cacheOverflowSize:50,
  cacheBlockSize:50,
  enableRtl: true,
  enableColResize:true,
  suppressAutoSize:true,
  enableSorting:true,
  rowSelection: 'multiple',
  rowDeselection:true,
  enableStatusBar:true,
  alwaysShowStatusBar:true,
  enableRangeSelection:true,
  rowGroupPanelShow: "always",
  animateRows: true,
  groupDefaultExpanded: -1,
  autoGroupColumnDef: { field: "city" },
  columnTypes: this.columnTypes
};
```

Can you please assist or get any idea to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have grouping in your app I guess you must have aggrid enterprise.

In that case you should use either the enterprise or viewport row-model. Right now you are rendering all 50.000 rows every time an update (like scrolling down a pixel) has to be made.

We are not using enterprise, so I can only link you to the official docs:

- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-enterprise-model/
- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-viewport/

But when we changed from standard row-model to infinite-scrolling (which has most features of enterprise) it was a big difference at 1000 rows already.

We also did other optimizations like removing input-components and replacing them with aggrid-cell-editors (which have only one input-listener for the whole column) but switching the row-model was by far the biggest performance improvement.